# Running coverlet on AppVeyor with message "vstest.console process failed to connect to testhost process"

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage, appveyor

When I try to run [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) on [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/giacomelli/geneticsharp/build/2.0.141) with the command:

```
dotnet test GeneticSharp.Domain.UnitTests -f netcoreapp2.0 /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
```

I received the message below:

> vstest.console process failed to connect to testhost process after 90
>   seconds. This may occur due to machine slowness, please set
>   environment variable VSTEST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to increase timeout.

Incrementing VSTEST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT did not solve.

The command runs with no problem on my local Windows and Mac machines.

Comment: To isolate the problem - does it work without `/p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover`?

Comment: Yeah, it does with only `dotnet test GeneticSharp.Domain.UnitTests -f netcoreapp2.0`